# KAFKA 3.5.1 create replica on controller

Tags: apache-kafka, controller, kraft

I have configuration 5 nodes, 4 broker+controller and 1 controller.
Create topic with replication factor 5, and it is created, and describe show that topic partition have 5 replicas.

```
/opt/kafka/latest/bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --bootstrap-server=dc1-prod-kafka-001-vs:9092 --replication-factor 5 --partitions 1 --topic test5
```

```
/opt/kafka/latest/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic test5 --bootstrap-server=dc1-prod-kafka-001-vs:9092
Topic: test5 TopicId: amuqr8EgRmqeKryUHZwsMA PartitionCount: 1 ReplicationFactor: 5 Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824
Topic: test5 Partition: 0 Leader: 3 Replicas: 3,4,1,2,5 Isr: 3,4,1,2
```

Replicas 5 and ISR 4.
Why does kafka initially allow you to create a replica on the controller node, although in reality the replica is not created on the controller node and there are no topic files in the log directory.

Is this expected behavior or not? Thanks.

I want to understand whether such behavior is the norm for Kafka

Comment: You'll need to share `process.roles` of your brokers. Are they both brokers and controllers? How do you know which one is a controller just based on the ids?

Comment: The bootstrap server argument isn't telling where to create anything, only how to reach one or more nodes in the cluster

Comment: 4 process.roles=broker,controller
1 process.roles=controller
my config from first node

Comment: listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,CONTROLLER://:9093
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://dc1-prod-kafka:9092
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/opt/kafka/kafka_2.13-3.5.1/logs/kraft-combined-logs

Comment: num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=4
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=4
transaction.state.log.min.isr=3
default.replication.factor=4
min.insync.replicas=3
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

Comment: node id from 1 up to 5 , controller id=5

Comment: Thanks. In the future, please [edit] your question to include formatted code blocks rather than comments